# NGINX won't load CSS files randomly

Tags: nginx, virtualhost

I recently moved from apache2 to nginx.

Everything works fine but sometimes (only like 2% of the time), loading will be pretty slow for like 5-10 sec and then the html will load but the css won't.

It's not a performance problem as i had already the bug in preProd with only me allowed on the server (blocked all IPs but me with UFW). I thought this was because i was refreshing while uploading files at that time, but now that we are live, people complain about it without me pushing files.

Nginx directly serve PHP/HTML/CSS/JS files. I also have a nodejs server for handling websocket, but that's the only thing it does.

I didn't tweak nginx conf and this is my vhost:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.mywebsite.com mywebsite.com;

    return 301 https://mywebsite.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name www.mywebsite.com;

    return 301 $scheme://mywebsite.com$request_uri;
}

server {

    ## SSL settings

    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;

    server_name mywebsite.com;

    root /var/www/mywebsite.com;

    index index.html index.php;


    location ~ /(includes|back/logs|ipn/includes|js_uncompiled|backups) {
        deny all;
        return 403;
    }


    #static file 404's aren't logged and expires header is set to maximum age
    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico)$ {
        access_log off;
        expires max;
    }
    
    access_log off;


    location ^~ /socket.io {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy false;

      proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
      proxy_redirect off;

      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
    }

    location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault. Any logs?

Comment: Nothing in nginx logs and it does happens only 2% of the time so that's hard to reproduce.